# Laravel - Mysql operations on table with two text columns take too much time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, text

my app is written in laravel framework. In one of my MySQL tables I have over 300000 rows . In this table I have two text columns storing item descriptions (descriptions usually contain between 2000 to 6000 chars). Queries on this table run very slow (I added indexes). I also have soft delete trait on the model. Even simple: `select count(*) as aggregate from`offers_flats`where`offers_flats`.`deleted_at`is null` takes about 11 seconds.. What can I do to speed this up?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped. I didn't have index on deleted_at before. Sadly, now I see there's one more thing which slows my query. I have a integer timestamp column which stores unix timestamp in it. When I do 'ORDER BY timestamp_priority DESC' then it slows the query (I added index to this column). ORDER BY timestamp_priority ASC works perfectly fast, but DESC works slow.. Can I do something with this?

Comment: EDIT: problem solved. It was not the timestamp_priority column's fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offers_flats` has index on field `deleted_at` ?

*if not, so add index to that field and try.*

Soft delete is nice thing, but it does not add index on that field and it's correct that it does not do that.

Because it's just a trait, adding index to `deleted_at` field must be done in migrations.